# dice coefficient and dice loss very low in UNET segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mask, dice

I'm doing binary segmentation using UNET. My dataset is composed of images and masks. I divided the images and masks into different folders ( `train_images`, `train_masks`, `val_images` and `val_masks`). Then I performed Data Augmentation.

```py
#Define the generator.
#We are not doing any rotation or zoom to make sure mask values are not interpolated.
#It is important to keep pixel values in mask as 0, 1, 2, 3, .....
def trainGenerator(train_img_path, train_mask_path):
    
    img_data_gen_args = dict(horizontal_flip=True,
                      vertical_flip=True,
                      fill_mode='reflect',shear_range=0.5, 
                      rotation_range=50,
                      zoom_range=0.2,
                      width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,
                      rescale=1/255.)
            
                      
    mask_data_gen_args = dict(horizontal_flip=True,
                      vertical_flip=True,
                      fill_mode='reflect',shear_range=0.5, 
                      rotation_range=50,
                      zoom_range=0.2,
                      width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,
                      preprocessing_function = lambda x: np.where(x>0, 1, 0).astype(x.dtype)) #Binarize the output again. 

            
                    
    
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**img_data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**mask_data_gen_args)
   
    
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_img_path,
        class_mode = None,
        color_mode = 'grayscale',
        target_size=(512,512),
        batch_size = batch_size,
        seed = seed)
    
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_mask_path,
        class_mode = None ,
        color_mode = 'grayscale',
        target_size=(512,512),
        batch_size = batch_size,
        seed = seed)
    
    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
    return train_generator'''
```

And this produced:

```
Found 2942 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 2942 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 318 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 318 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

Then I built the model

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
#Contraction path
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(inputs)
c1= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
c1= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
c2= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
c2= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
c3= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c3)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
c3= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
c4= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
c4= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
c5= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)
c5= tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(c5)
#Expansive path 
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)
 
u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)
 
u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)
 
u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
 
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
```

```py
from keras import backend as K


def dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred, smooth=0.0001):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)

    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)

    return ((2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) +
            K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth))


def dice_coefficient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1.0-dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred)
LR = 0.00001
optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)
metrics = ['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall',  dice_coefficient ]
model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=dice_coefficient_loss, metrics=metrics)
history=model.fit(train_generator,
          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=val_generator,
          validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch)
```

*However results are very bad and I can't understand why
Any ideas ?
Thanks *

Comment: Have completely the same situation with such UNet model. Try to use: `tf.keras.metrics.IoU` it should be faster.